# WSL win-kex pick up windows scale 1.25%?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2, tigervnc

I am using kali in wsl. When I launch **win-kex in windows mode**, it (xtigervnc) pick up windows default scal which is 1.25% (windows 11). It is not looking nice and blurry.

Command to launch win-kex:
`win-kex --win -s`

Issue Image:
[Blurry-kali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnhNl.jpg)

**Not the permanent solution:**

When I scal down windows to 100% (not default value), wsl kali is looking as it should be in virutal machine but windows is so zoomed out and hard to navigate.

Windows 11 after scalling to 100%:
[zoomed out windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzODd.png)

After kali: [Perfect scal of kali](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b72jW.jpg)

> *Windows is not looking nice and Either I have to compromise with windows or kali.*

**Is there any solutions?**